# Using result_array PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, phpexcel

Good day, I'm trying to export some records from my table with phpexcel. Please check myscript first.

```
function ceks()
            {
                $this->load->library('excels');
                $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
                $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("Export Penilaian");
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from 
                                            (
                         select distinct TOP 201233 row, a.tanggal,b.OutletCode,i.Description areaoutlet,c.Nilai,a.Nip,b.Fullname,a.KodePenilaian,f.Description as posisilama,
                        d.Description as posisibaru
                        from penilaian_header a 
                            left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip
                            left join Position f on b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode
                            left join Position d on a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
                            left join arealeader g on g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode
                            left join outlet h on g.OutletCode = h.OutletCode
                            left join area i on i.areacode = h.areacode
                            left join (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand DESC) AS Row, 
                                            Nilai,KodePenilaianH from penilaian_Detail
                                            ) c on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH where h.AreaCode like '%$area%' and Periode like '%$periode%' $kondisi order by i.Description asc) nilai 
                                            pivot
                                            (
                                              sum(nilai)
                                              for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
                                            ) piv;");
                $col = 0;
                foreach ($fields as $field)
                {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
                    $col++;
                }
                $row = 2;       
                    foreach($query->result_array() as $data)
                {
                    $col = 0;
                    foreach ($fields as $field)
                    {
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
                        $col++;
                    }
                    $row++;
                }
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Products_'.date('dMy').'.xls"');
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                ob_end_clean();
                ob_start();
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
            }
}
```

I'm using `result_array()` inside my script above. There isn't any result inside exported excel file. But, when i'm only using `result()` the result is showing up. But, A value at coloumn like [1],[2],[3],[4] & [5] didn't show.

result from `print_r($query->result_array())`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tanggal] => 2016-05-30
            [OutletCode] => K-ARN3
            [areaoutlet] => JAKARTA
            [Nip] => 1411751
            [Fullname] => SITI MASITOH
            [KodePenilaian] => PE0000001
            [posisilama] => ADMINISTRASI OUTLET
            [posisibaru] => VISUAL MERCHANDISE OUTLET
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 7
            [5] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tanggal] => 2016-05-30
            [OutletCode] => K-BJDM2
            [areaoutlet] => BANJARMASIN
            [Nip] => 1500281
            [Fullname] => HENDRIYANI
            [KodePenilaian] => PE0000005
            [posisilama] => ADMINISTRASI OUTLET
            [posisibaru] => VISUAL MERCHANDISE OUTLET
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 7
        )
)
```

Comment: Does `result_array()` return an array of scalar values (as shown in your print_r)? Or an array of objects? You're  addressing as ` $data->$field` which suggests objects

Comment: above is when i print_r `print_r($query->result_array())`

Comment: Then using `$data->$field` is invalid (and you should actually be seeing a warning message telling you that, because $data isn't an object but an array.... use `$data[$field]` to access array elements

Comment: dude, thanks it works. I can't see any error message because i turn it off. Well i will turn it on for now.

Comment: @YVS1102 is this solved ??

Comment: @Abdulla yes it is

Comment: @YVS1102 add self answer and close this question as open